# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/cucumberexpressions/ParameterTypeRegistry error when ran maven install using jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, testing, cucumber

Below is the error is shown in the Jenkins console output

---

### T E S T S

Running StepDefinitions.testRunnerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE! - in StepDefinitions.testRunnerTest
StepDefinitions.testRunnerTest  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/cucumberexpressions/ParameterTypeRegistry

Comment: Below is my POM

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).